# How do I get my toddler to eat fruit?

Tags: toddler, health, food

I have a 2 year old kid who does not like fruits in any form.

We have tried a lot but he would not eat fruits. Even if we make fruit shake with pieces of fruits in it, he would drink the shake and remove the fruits from his mouth.

Should we be worried about his dislike for fruits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When he was two, our son really seemed to dislike bananas. We kept pushing them, because they are an inexpensive and healthy snack. It took probably 4-6 months of having him try one at least once or twice a week, but now he loves them.

The key, in our house at least, is that the kids are required to try everything we put on their plate (at least 1 bite). If they don't like it, they are welcome to spit it out on their plate and not required to finish it; but we do require that they try it before they can leave the table. Just as with any other rules, you have to be willing to stick to your guns and not give in: make rules you believe in, and enforce them 99.99% of the time. (The .01% is reserved for public outings or special occasions where you don't want to make a scene, like Christmas dinner.)

Answer (score 5):

As well as us joining in with eating fruit, one that worked for one of our kids (who really didn't want to eat fruit) was to make smoothies. We put a wide range of things into these: bananas, apples, oranges, mango etc and because it was a drink, she had no problems with them.

So until she finally came round to liking fruits in their natural form, we managed to get around 5 a day into her diet this way.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will definately try it out. Thanks!

Comment: We did this with our first-born to get her to *drink her milk*, slowly cutting back the fruit until she was just drinking milk, then she loved it.

Answer (score 2):

Two things have worked great for us here:

1. Having him present at family meals where we all are eating fruit and liking it
2. We got a pacifier at Babies R Us with a net, where you can add pieces of fruit and he can suck on them. It took some time but eventually he took to them.

I wouldn't worry if he is not taking to fruits right now, but I definitely would not stop relaxedly trying.

Answer (score 2):

I make banana "ice cream". Peel and freeze whole bananas (it's a good way to use up the spotty ones at the bottom of the fruit bowl). When they are frozen, give them a whizz in the food processor (it makes a bit of a racket at first). Result - consistency of soft ice cream, but contains nothing except bananas.

Answer (score 0):

Did he ever like fruit?

Kids seem to go through 'difficult' phases where they inexplicably stop liking stuff they used to, but they generally grow out of that, though tastes do change with time.

You could try leaving bite-sized bits of various fruits available for him to sample when he's not 'working'.